# Pattern matching and printing above line in tcl

Tags: tcl, yaml

Hi all I need help here.. I have a yml file which consist xyz cores name I need extract each core name and print them .  the pattern of yml file is

```
cores:
   usb_1.0
     STATS:
        power 
       -------

       --------

  usb_2.0
     STATS:
       memory 

      ------
      ------

  usb_3.0 

   STATS

     cpu:

  -------- 
  =--------

  pce_1
    STATS:

    reg:

-----
---
```

So if see I have some core name like usb , pice , like soo on ..

so I need get the name , what I am thinking is use STATS keywork and print above link name , here is code

read file using set command and then use regexp

```
set fp [open ram.yml r]
set file_data [read $fp]
regexp  ??????
```

Comment: Tcl _really_ cares about spaces between arguments to commands.

Comment: You could use an RE like `regexp -line -all -inline {^ {2,3}\m[^[:upper:]]*$} $file_data`, but that is so brittle (and vaguely villainous) it should be played by Samuel L Jackson with a glass cane. As Donal wrote, use the `yaml` package instead.

Comment: Why was this tagged Perl? I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way of parsing YAML with Tcl is with the [`yaml` package](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/yaml/yaml.html) in Tcllib.